# Prevent infinite auto-refreshing on mobile browsers while keeping responsive functionality?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, refresh

Kind of getting ahead of myself with the discovery of the javascript auto-refresh script..

```
//refresh page on browser resize
$(window).bind('resize', function(e)
{
  console.log('window resized..');
  this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
  /* true to fetch page from server */
});
```

I was stoked to have it be used as a way for my site to auto-adjust it's nav bar no matter what size the screen is. My goal was mainly to have the nav bar's menu icon "float on right" but still be visible on the screen, even on small screens. And I know there's a better way going about this, but for the moment this method seemed to work best via my limited javascript knowledge. No judgement! :-P

Anyway here's my problem. Although the nav bar re-sizes itself upon refresh, on small screens and mobile browsers it will REFRESH the page anytime the user swipes down on the site. The same happens for most tablets and smartphones.

To see what I'm talking about here is an alternate link to my website (Updating my database atm so I apologize for the horrid address numbers)

```
http://69.194.231.142    <---Please copy/paste this address into major/mobile browsers for diagnosis
```

it works great on laptops and large screens, but when viewing this site on a phone or tablet it will either refresh for infinity or refresh whenever you scroll.

If there's any way to solve this little riddle of nuisance code please let me know. Or at least, a better way to go about coding it so it only refreshes ONCE and not indefinitely. I don't know if this is possible though so any alternative solutions are welcome.

Maybe there's a way for just the CSS that makes up the nav to refresh and not the entire page? Either that or something that lets the page refresh just one time would be superb :-D

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think reloading the page in response to resize is a good plan. On the desktop when the user resizes by dragging multiple resize events are triggered. _"I was stoked to have it be used as a way for my site to auto-adjust it's nav bar no matter what size the screen is."_ - Have you tried doing this via CSS so that it happens automatically without any JS?

Comment: Why are you doing a reload at all?  You shouldn't have to reload the content/page.  You should be able to either just let the CSS relayout things or if you have some JS that participates in page loading, you can just call that JS upon the resize to readjust.  You should not be reloading the page.

Comment: When the "refresh JS" is disabled, the issue that I begin to have is that the nav bar doesn't automatically adjust to align the menu properly. It always seems to be off center... I tried using percentages and what not but in the end it's still giving me issues. If anyone has a way to do this purely in CSS (automatic resizing) that would help. I just want to have it so the menu items stay centered and the mobile button STAYS on the right no matter what size the browser window is and doesn't get clipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

Seems that my browser was using a cdn. So I had to flush the cache on the server to see the changes. Removed the JS refresh script and fixed the navbar to be set to "relative" when in mobile view. This way I don't have to worry about the spacing! It was originally being crossed out from this other javascript that makes the nav bar sticky, but the script also made the navbar stick on mobile view, which was messing up my layout and causing a lot of lag upon scrolling.

Fixing these little things made a big difference in my website usability. Now theres no refresh to worry about and the page stays centered on multiple screens.

Thanks all who suggested removal of the JS, Using CSS only worked like a charm!